# jQuery arrays and retrieve data and key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to jQuery and just wrote this small piece (with PHP knowledge) and was wondering a) would it work b) how would i return a value acording to its key value?

```
    var boxHeightArray = [];
    var boxNameArray = [];
    $("div[class=dropDiv]").each(function(i){   
        var height = $(this).height(true);
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    boxHeightArray[i] = height;
    boxNameArray[i] = name;
   });
```

regards

Comment: the height() command will takes only a string or number as a parameter argument (not a boolean) and is used to set the height of elements in the wrapped set. What are you trying to do here- `$(this).height(true);` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of objects:

```
    var boxInfo = [];//an array to store 'info' objects
    $("div[class=dropDiv]").each(function(i){   
        var height = $(this).height(true);
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var obj = { boxHeight: height, boxName: name };
        boxInfo.push(obj);
    });
```

Now each offset to `boxInfo` contains an object, you can traverse them like this:

```
$.each(boxInfo,function(i,n) {
    alert("Height of box at offset " + i + " is: " + n.boxHeight + " and name is: " + n.boxName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> how would i return a value acording to its key value?

What do you mean by this ?

You can use an associative array if you want instead of two arrays,
so that would mean something like

```
$("div[class=dropDiv]").each(function(i){   
  var height = $(this).height(true);
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
   hash[name]  = height;
  ihash[height]= name  ;
 });
```

So now you can return a name by knowing the height, and you can return a height by knowing the name.
(given that there are no duplicate names/heights).

Comment: the nearest structure to an associative array in JavaScript is an object. Using JavaScript arrays as associative arrays is not recommended as they are not designed for this- http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/